# Sympy.plot not drawing graph for square root for x > 0

Tags: python, sympy

If I use sympy.plot for drawing graph of x^2, it's ok.
But when I want to  draw graph of x^0.5 or sqrt(x), sympy.plot  draw only coordinate axis, but not a graph.

Code:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot

init_printing(use_unicode = false, wrap_line=false, no_global = true)

x = symbols("x")
f = x**(0.5)
plot(f, xlim=[0,10], ylim=[0,200])
```

So, this code draws no grpah. If i use sqrt(x) instead of x**(0.5) - also no graph. X is always positive: xlim=[0,10]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. X can't be negative, and we must  set limit for x not by xlim, but so:

```
plot(f, (x, 0,100))
```